# Optimizing threading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have three issues with the attached code, which has to do with threading. I need to make function calls to provide information about the following three items:

1. Is the thread `vecOfThreads[1]` empty without any tasks currently running on it
2. Is the thread `vecOfThreads[0]` `joinable()` but not ready to be `join()`ed
3. This would be the else statement of 2). If a thread is `joinable()` and won't wait to `join()` then go ahead and `join()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono> // std::chrono::microseconds
#include <thread> // std::this_thread::sleep_for
#include <vector>

void f1();

void f1() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds {3});
    std::cout << "DONE SLEEPING!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int processor_count = 2;  // consider that this CPU has two processors
    std::vector<std::thread> vecOfThreads(processor_count);

    std::thread t1(f1);
    vecOfThreads[0] = std::move(t1);

    if (vecOfThreads[0].joinable()) {  // how to check to see if vecOfThreads[1] would be good to start a process on?
        std::cout << "this is joinable, but not yet ready to be joined \n";
        std::cout << "How to know: \n \t 1) if the thread is not being used "
                     "\n \t 2) if the thread is in use, but not yet ready to be `join()`ed \n \t "
                     "3) if the thread is both joinable and will not wait for a join()" << std::endl;
        vecOfThreads[0].join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with

```
g++ -std=c++17 -pthread
```

I would like to be able to submit say 12 tasks, but I only have 2 threads available. I want for a new task to be submitted right away when one of the threads finish. Is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The example is a bit contrived.  There's no real case for "starting a process" on a thread whose only job is to sleep 3 seconds and then exit.  It sounds like you're asking about how to queue and assign tasks to a thread pool.  This sort of thing is usually controlled using condition variables.

Comment: This is just a minimal example, the sleeping three seconds is to indicate that I don't want for the program to recursively wait at `join()`. If by thread pool you mean being able to submit say 12 tasks and each time a thread opens up submit a task right away to the open thread, then yes thread pool.

Comment: No, a thread pool is where you have a fixed number of threads and a shared queue.  A single thread will pull an item off the queue for processing.  When the queue is empty the thread goes to sleep until instructed to shutdown by the pool.  The whole point is that with a thread pool you don't incur the cost of starting/stopping worker threads, and you don't allocate an excessive number of threads.  Anyway, yes you generally use a `condition_variable` with a `mutex` to control sequencing.  Each thread waits on the condition variable until it's signalled, indicating something is in the queue.

Comment: Yes, I think a thread pool is what I want, although I want to use as many threads as is necessary (hence optimization). Its a lot of number crunching. Do you think it would be better for me to write my own thread pool or are there any open source libraries available for C++ threading?

Comment: I think that's entirely up to you, depending on your requirements and goals.  Your operating system might provide its own thread pool via API (Windows does, for example).  Intel TBB or `boost::asio::thread_pool` are also popular choices.  Sometimes for very specific uses you need to roll your own.  Writing a performant thread pool is not actually as easy as it sounds.  But it is a fun learning exercise.

Comment: Many standard algorithms, like [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), have an overload where you can specify an _ExecutionPolicy_. These overloads use TBB or whatever is available to the implementation to do their work. Often using a thread pool.

Comment: I see you edited more info into your comment.  If you're doing raw crunching you might consider using frameworks like OpenMP for loop paralellization.

Comment: @paddy Looks like boost is the easy option, but I'm sure its not as optimized. After I get the code running accurately I'll have to come back and look into OpenMP and other techniques (been interested in learning MPI C++ for quite some time). Thank for the intro.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Taking a look at that I'm not sure what it means. I'd have to see an example that I understood to have any idea how that could help.

Comment: Here's a short [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298350/7582247). Each `sort` inside the `for_each` is likely running in a thread picked form a thread pool.